# Getting Google Map with Ajax, content missing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I promise I've tried searching for other answers, however I have not been able to find anything that has helped. Possibly because I haven't able to correlate my findings to what I have.

I have a Wordpress site and I'm trying to display a specific map based on the dropdown selection. I have about 100 maps that are being generated by a WP plugin.

I can't just load all of them at once because obviously the page would never load and I would probably crash a few browsers out there, it is simply too heavy.

I tried loading them all on another WP page and calling them via Ajax, however the some of the code inside is missing. JavaScript is there and everything, however not the HTML after the first DIV.

Not sure if it's a crossdomain issue or what, but I'm stumped. The map that I intend to load by default loads just fine, so I'm assuming all the necessary libraries have already been called, then again I could be very wrong.

Any help or nudge in the right direction greatly appreciated. Beer on me if you live in BK

Thanks!!

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/?page_id=94',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
        $('#test .1-1').html($(data).find('.1-1').html());
    }
});

<div class="map 1-1">
    <div id="cpm_XUf9m5" class="cpm-map" style="display:none; width:100%; height:450px; clear:both; overflow:hidden; margin:0px auto;">
        <!-- MISSING HTML -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // All JavaScript that is normally loaded is there, not pasting it to keep it short
    </script>

    <noscript> codepeople-post-map require JavaScript </noscript>
    <script>
        // All JavaScript that is normally loaded is there, not pasting it to keep it short        
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: in general - wordpress has a built in url for ajax `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>`

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm missing something here. Not sure I follow, doesn't **admin_url** just return the path/URL to the admin area. How does that help?

Comment: thats how you load ajax in wordpress see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710728/how-to-load-ajax-in-wordpress)