# How can I include Wordpress loop output into JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a script that randomly displays text when a button is clicked, how can I substitute the manual list with a Wordpress get_post() loop?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("input[id='mantra']").keyup(function() {
        $("#preview").text($("input[id='mantra']").val());
    })

    // I wish to substitute these variables with a list of post titles.
    var randomStrings = [
     "I AM DIVINE PERFECTION",
     "LET GO. LET GOD.",
     "FOLLOW YOUR HEART",
    ];

    var randomDiv = document.getElementById("preview");
    var changer = document.getElementById("mantra");

    document.getElementById("myMantraButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
      randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random()*randomStrings.length-1));
      newText = randomStrings[randomIndex];
      randomDiv.innerHTML = newText;
      changer.value = newText;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried/read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710728/how-to-load-ajax-in-wordpress)