# How to make an ajax call with parameters into Wordpress site

Tags: ajax, wordpress, parameters

I have a simple web with an ajax call with parameters that works fine alone:
http://www.colome.org/utils/

This is the sample code:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="codi.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<section id="main">
    <table id="tng" class="datagrid">
        <tbody>
        </tr><tr>
            <td width="50%" align="right"><b>Host or IP:</b></td>
            <td><input  id="ip" size="20" value="" ></td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="Ping()">Ping</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  ...
</section>  
<h3 id="notification"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a function "**Ping**" inside **codi.js** that makes the ajax call

**codi.js:**

```
function Ping()
{
    $("#image").show();
        var ip=document.getElementById('ip');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://...../ping.php",
        cache: false,
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //dataType: "json",
        data: {"ip" : ip.value}, 
        success: onSuccesPing,
        error: onErrorPing,
        crossDomain:true
    });

}
function onSuccesPing(data,status)
{
   document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML=data;
}
function onErrorPing(data,status)
{
   document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML=data.responseText);
}
```

And finally the **ping.php** code, very simple:

```
<?php
$ip =   $_POST["ip"];
exec("ping -c 3 ".$ip." 2>&1", $output, $status);
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    echo ($value.'<br>');
}

?>
```

I was trying to integrate this code to my wordpress website, like the example below:
[For example this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710728/how-to-load-ajax-in-wordpress)
 but I don't know how to pass parameters to the ajax call, please can you help me? thanks.

Comment: No one has been found in this issue?
it would be interesting to know how do. I lost several hours in google without clear results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after several days, finally I found the solution, I hope that it will help those who have had this problem:

first, I was created a post inside a wordpress whit this html code:

```
<section id="main">
<table id="tng" class="datagrid">
    <thead><tr><th colspan="3"> 
        Sample ping App
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width="50%" align="right"><b>Host or IP:</b></td>
        <td><input  id="ip" size="20" value="" ></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="PING()">Ping</button></td>
        <td> <img id="image" src="spinner.gif" alt="wait..." style="display: none;"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the only important thing is the onclick event for the button that calls de function **PING()**

Then upload the js (**ping.js**) inside my theme js folder in my case:
**public_html/wp-content/themes/metone_wp/js**:

```
function PING(){
    $imatge=document.getElementById('image');
    $imatge.show();
    $ip=document.getElementById('ip');
    $val=ip.value;
    $params={action:'ping_php',ip: $val}

    jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
       cache: false,
       //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       //dataType: "json",
       data: $params, 
       success: onSuccesPing,
       error: onErrorPing
       //error: onErrorPing,
       //crossDomain:true
     });
   //another way to make the same
   // jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, $params,function (response){
   //   document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML=response;
   //   document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
   //  });
}
function onSuccesPing(data,status)
{
   jQuery("#notification").fadeIn(0); 
   document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML=data;
   document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
   jQuery("#notification").delay(5200).fadeOut(300);

}
function onErrorPing(data,status)
{
   jQuery("#notification").fadeIn(0);  
   document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML=data.responseText;
   document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
   jQuery("#notification").delay(5200).fadeOut(300);
}
```

The trick to pass paramters to the ajax call is the line:

```
 $params={action:'ping_php',ip: $val}
```

**$params** is an array of parameters, is necesary to have a mandatory parameter **"action"** that refers the php function defined below normaly at the functions.php of wordpress theme.

The parameters can be accessed at the php function as **$_POST** variables in my case **$_POST['ip']**.

to define the functions in wordpress I was used the theme functions.php, and and this piece of code:

```
//----------------------------- test utils ini-----------------------------------------
function ping_php ()
{
     $ip=$_POST['ip'];
    exec("ping -c 3 ".$ip." 2>&1", $output, $status);
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
        echo ($value.'<br>');
    }
   die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ping_php', 'ping_php' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ping_php', 'ping_php' );
function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('ajax-script',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/ping.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); 
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script'); // jQuery will be included automatically
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
//---------------------------test utils end ----------------------------------------------
```

is important to folow the correct order to enqueue the script

1. First the **wp_register_script**: include the directory of the js file and jquery enabled
2. then **wp_localize_script**: usefull to pass variables from wordpress to my script in my case the url of ajax processing: **ajaxurl**
3. finally **wp_enqueue_script**

It is important to add **wp_die()** or **die()** at the end of the php function, if not the function returns **"0"**

It is also very inportant that the function names match exactly:

- add_action( 'wp_ajax_**ping_php**', 'ping_php' );
- add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_**ping_php**', 'ping_php' );

with the parameter **"action"** of the ajax call

Comment: You explain in great detail which is appreciated. I overlooked getting variables by using $var = $_GET[{var_name}]. Thanks for the reminder