# wordpress/php - Ajax/Jquery send gravity forms drop down to another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to populate the gravity form that users fill in(mysite.com/gform/), dynamically in one of the pages for viewing based on the first drop down select value. For this, In all the pages for viewing the form's content, I need to know the drop down input that has been selected. In fact, I want when the form submits to another page(mysite.com/gview1/), I should have access to select value on the anotherpage, so that I load the form data if that select value is a specific value in another page .Here's what I've done so far:

-In the gravityforms.php 's GFForms class: In the init function I registered my hook, and gave it access to all users as such:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_enqueue', 'my_enqueue' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_enqueue', 'my_enqueue' );
```

and after "maybe_process_form()" static function in this file, I added my_enqueue:

```
function my_enqueue() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxSendField', plugins_url( '/js/ajaxSendField.js', 
__FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'ajaxSendField', 'data', 
    array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
```

In which input_3 is the select's name.

-Activated gravity forms ajax, and created a file named ajaxSendField.js in the js folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#input_2_3').on("change", function(event) {
ajaxSend(this.form);
});

ajaxSend(this.form);
event.preventDefault();

function ajaxSend(form1) {
$.ajax({
url: 'mysite.com/gview1/',
type: 'POST',
var data = {
    'action': 'my_enqueue',
    'selectedValue': $('#input_2_3').val();
    }
});

ajaxurl = "../../../../admin-ajax.php";
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
alert('Got this from the server: ' + response); 
});
});
}
</script>
```

In which, input_2_3 is the id of the drop down select when I inspect it via chrome. So far, the onchange event should have been set in the form, if we want to pass the value by selecting a drop down menu, rather than submitting the form. But, when I view the page source, it doesn't show up. So, I think the javascript file is not loaded.

-In the template of the page for viewing the submitted value called custompage1.php, I have added the code below, above its footer:

```
<?php
echo "Hi ".$_POST['selectedValue']."<br>"."Bye for now";
echo $_POST['input_3']."<br>"."Bye";
?>
```

In which input_3 is the select's name. But upon form submission(Ajax), I only get

Hi

Bye for now

Bye

Are all the snippets correct? Am I inserting the snippets in the right place?

Comment: event.preventDefault(); isn't doing anything here because it's outside the on('change') function. I'd doubt that's got anything to do with your problem though. Have you checked your ajax request on the network tab of your chrome console. You should see it return with status 200 when the ajax is submitted and you should also be able to see the values of the data being sent.

Comment: so, you think all the code should work?

Comment: Not necessarily. Check the network tab in your console and see if your getting any errors or 404's or anything like that. If you're not getting any errors and you can see the data being passed then we can rule out a problem with your ajax and maybe look at your html or php instead.

Comment: one moment please

Comment: I don't see status 200, and no values are shown. what's the problem?

Comment: Well if your not getting a status 200 response then your ajax isn't been sent at all. But in your question you're said your getting the response without the data so... are you sure? Try adding this to see if the change event is firing correctly. jQuery('#input_2_3').on("change", function(event) {
console.log('test');
});

Comment: I just remembered aswell... I had a problem with this a while back. You have to do ajax calls a certain way with Wordpress submitting it to the admin-ajax.php. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710728/how-to-load-ajax-in-wordpress . I'm going to log out now but will have a look at this again later if it hasn't already been answered.