# Data insertion in WordPress using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In WordPress, I'm trying to insert data into database using Ajax.

**functions.php**

```
function dataInsert(){
    global $wpdb, $slidecount;
    $slidecount = 25;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'custom_table',
        array(
            'slidecount'=> $slidecount
        )
    );
    die();
    return true;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_dataInsert', 'dataInsert');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dataInsert', 'dataInsert');
```

**JavaScript**// *I put insertDataJS function in footer.php*

```
<script>
function insertDataJS(){
   console.log("insertDataJS start");
   jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: dataInsert.ajaxurl,
      data: {"action": "dataInsert"},
      success: function(data){
           //alert(data);
      }
   });
   console.log("insertDataJS end");
}
</script>
```

When I tried to call the `insertDataJS()` function, I get the error messages below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dataInsert is not defined
>       at insertDataJS ((index):303)
>       at HTMLDivElement. ((index):444)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at n.fn.init.triggerHandler (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at Object.changeTo (eval at  (layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js?ver=6.7.6:13),
>   :1:53999)
>       at Object.eval (eval at  (layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js?ver=6.7.6:13),
>   :1:131795)
>       at Object.g._callback (greensock.js?ver=1.19.0:20)
>       at Object.g.render (greensock.js?ver=1.19.0:21)

Please share any idea!

Comment: You got here a good start of response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710728/how-to-load-ajax-in-wordpress In fact you haven't declare you variable dataInsert in javascript by the wp_localize_script wordpress function

Comment: Easiest solution is - replace `dataInsert.ajaxurl` with `'<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>'`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Inazo and @Outsource suggested in their answer, I sloved it by using the ajaxurl javascript variable to reference the admin-ajax.php file. I declared this on the front end, by putting the following in the footer.php of my theme.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```