# Run button click on WP Admin with Add_action

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a simple button in my ADMIN wordpress.

```
<button type = "button"> RUN </ button>
```

I would like a function that is in function.php only executed when I click RUN.

I can add my function:

```
add_action ('my_action', 'my_function');
```

But how do I call the function when I click the button?

Comment: Look into using AJAX. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807368/how-to-use-wordpress-functions-in-an-ajax-call

Comment: @disinfor Thank you very much for the answer, but I do not need to be ajax in this case, do you know how to do it without using ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider changing your button to a form submit button instead. Just create a standard form, and leave the `action` blank. So something like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="mysubmitbtn" value="RUN" />
</form>
```

And then in your `functions.php` file, you can add an `init` action like:

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_my_form' );
function process_my_form() {
     if( isset( $_POST['mysubmitbtn'] ) ) {
          // process $_POST data here
     }
}
```

You might also want to read about the special WordPress submit/save button https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button for building Admin forms.

Check out https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces as well, to take advantage of some of WordPress security features.

Comment: Thank you so much @signal2013, this worked for me. Thanks also for the indicated links